(Reference request) Popular math book about asymptotics
I was wondering if people know of any popular math books aimed at high schoolers or maybe starting undergraduates about asymptotics or dynamical systems? For dynamical systems, I know of Phil Holmes' "Celestial Encounters" which gives a historical account of the origins of dynamical systems theory, but I think it's not super accessible.
Thank you!

A more accessible popular book on dynamical systems is "Newton's Clock: Chaos in the Solar System", by Ivars Peterson.
